# NPM errors while installing react.js

Tags: reactjs, npm

NPM errors while installing react.js

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fRAy.png**strong text**

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:
Force to the latest version
Just try to run the create command with force to the latest version. Just like this:

```
npx create-react-app@latest_version my-app --use-npm
```

And the latest version is 5.0.0 so just try this command:

```
npx create-react-app@5.0.0 my-app
```

Now, your error must be solved.

Solution 2:

Clear the cache You just need to clear your cache and then you can create a new React project. First of all, clear the cache by running this command:

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

If it does not work, use this and try again: Delete everything from this path.

C:\Users\Your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

On macOS (and Linux), it’s ~/.npm/_npx. You can drop it in your terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/.npm/_npx
```

Or try the command npm cache clean --force using administrator mode in your terminal. Now, just re-enter your create command.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this command **npm cache clean --force** then run **npm install -g create-react-app@latest [here your app name]** then you won't be able to see this e